# Costs of operations in Java

Tags: java

Is there a why to tell, how expensive an operation for the processor in millisecons or flops is?
I would be intrested in "instanceof", casts (I heard they are very "expensive").

Are there some studies about that?

Comment: This depends on the VM implementation and underlying processor architecture, and potentially other things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will depend on which JVM you're using, and the cost of many operations can vary even within the same JVM, depending on the exact situation and how much optimization the JIT has performed.

For example, a virtual method call can still be inlined by the Hotspot JIT - so long as it hasn't been overridden by anything else. In some cases with the server JIT it can *still* be inlined with a quick type test, for up to a couple of types.

Basically, JITs are complex enough that there's unlikely to be a meaningful general purpose answer to the question. You should benchmark your own specific situation in as real-world a way as possible. You should *usually* write code with primary goals of simplicit and readability - but *measure* the performance regularly.

Answer (score 7):

The time where counting instructions or cycles could give you a good idea about the performance of some code are long gone, thanks to many, many optimizations happening on all levels of software execution.

This is **especially** true for VM-based languages, where the JVM can simply skip some steps because it knows that it's not necessary.

For example, I've read some time ago in an article (I'll try to find and link it eventually) that these two methods are pretty much equivalent in cost (on the HotSpot JVM, that is):

```
public void frobnicate1(Object o) {
  if (!(foo instanceof SomeClass)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Oh Noes!");
  }
  frobnicateSomeClass((SomeClass) o);
}

public void frobnicate2(Object o) {
  frobnicateSomeClass((SomeClass) o);
}
```

Obviously the first method does more work, **but** the JVM knows that the type of `o` has already been checked in the `if` and can actually **skip** the type-check on the cast later on and make it a no-op.

This and many other optimizations make counting "flops" or cycles pretty much useless.

Generally speaking an `instanceof` check is relatively cheap. On the HotSpot JVM it boils down to a numeric check of the type id in the object header.

[This classic article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/devinsight_1/) describes why you should "Write Dumb Code".

There's also an article from 2002 that describes [how `instanceof` is optimized in the HotSpot JVM](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=583821).

Answer (score 3):

Once the JVM has warmed up most operations can be counted in nano-seconds (millionths of a milli-second)  When talking about something being expensive, you usually have to say its expensive relative to an alternative.  Its next to impossible to describe something as expensive in all cases.

Usually, the most important expense is your time (and other developers in your team)  Using `instanceof` can be expensive in development and code support time because it often indicates a poor design.  Using proper OOP techniques is usually a better idea.  The 10 nano-second an `instanceof` might take, is usually relatively trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of specific operations performed inside the CPU is almost never relavant for performance. If performance is bad, it's almost always because of IO (network, disk) or inefficient code. Writing efficient code is much more about finding a way to reduce the overall amount of operations rather than avoiding "costly" operations (except those that are orders of magnitude more costly, like IO).